# WCF- 1 service, multiple endpoints and multiple behaviours?

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I have 1 service and multiple endpoints as shown below. I want to have a general behaviour and overwrite my wshttpbinding with another behaviour but when I try that I receive error tells me

Parser Error Message: There is no endpoint behavior named 'CredentialValidator'.

what am I doing wrong?

```
 <services>
  <service name="myservice.Service.myserviceService" behaviorConfiguration="myserviceBehaviour">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="https://localhost:44300/myService.svc"/>
        <!--<add baseAddress="http://localhost:54941/myService.svc"/>-->
        <!--<add baseAddress="http://myservicewcf.myurl-staging.com/myService.svc"/>-->
        <add baseAddress="https://myservice.myurl-staging.com/myService.svc"/>
        <add baseAddress="https://myservice.production.com/myService.svc"/>
        <!--<add baseAddress="https://myservicetest.myurl-staging.com/myService.svc"/>-->
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint name="myserviceSoap12Endpoint" address="soap12" binding="customBinding"  bindingConfiguration="soap12selfBinding" contract="myservice.Service.ImyserviceService" behaviorConfiguration="CredentialValidator" />
    <endpoint name="myserviceWSHttpEndpoint" address="ws" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="myserviceWSHttpBinding" contract="myservice.Service.ImyserviceService"/>
    <endpoint name="myserviceBasicHttpEndpoint" address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="myserviceBasicHttpBinding" contract="myservice.Service.ImyserviceService"/>
    <!--<endpoint name="myserviceBasicHttpEndpoint2" address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="myserviceBasicHttpBinding" contract="myservice.Service.ImyserviceService2"/>-->
    <endpoint name="myserviceMexEndpointHttps" address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name ="CredentialValidator">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug
         includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
                                customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="myservice.Service.CustomUserNameValidator, myservice"/>           
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="myserviceBehaviour">
      <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress/>
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your `CredentialValidator`behavior in `<endpointBehaviors>` tags instead of `<serviceBehaviors>`.

Because the exception message clearly states that there is not any `endpointBehavior` with that name. So give it one! Like this:

```
<behaviors>
  **<endpointBehaviors>**
    <behavior name ="CredentialValidator">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/> 
    </behavior>
  **</endpointBehaviors>**

  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="myserviceBehaviour">
      <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress/>
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: Is it not for client side? I am trying this for service side. Basically I want to secure my custombinding with credentials while basichttp doesnt have this behaviour. I edited my code by additing credentials in the behaviour. EndpointBehaviour doesnt have serviceCredentials as expected.

Comment: btw error message doesnt tell me that "endpointbehaviour" but "endpoint behaviour" i dont know if it makes any difference as terms